# MatLab Bisection method - updating the limit for each iteration[help]

Tags: algorithms, matlab, bisection

So below I have a written function emplyoing a bisection algroithm for finding roots. One issue I have(if you can't find more that will say) is that I don't know how to incorporate a new limit for each loop(iteration).

You can see below where I've written "%update limit".

```
function [root, iter]= bisectoin(f,a,b,TOL)
i= 0;
while le(abs(a-b),TOL)
    m=(a+b)./2;
    if f(m)==0
        a=m;
        b=m;
    end
    if f(m)*f(b)<0
        a=m;
        %Update limit    
    if f(a)*f(m) <0   
        b=m;
       %Update limit

    end
       i = i+1;       
end
end
```

Latest version of code

```
function [root,iter]= bisectoin(f,a,b,TOL)
iter= 0;
while ge(abs(a-b),TOL)
    m=(a+b)./2;
    if f(m)==0
        a=m;
        b=m;
    end
    if f(m)*f(b)<0
        a=m;

    if f(a)*f(m) <0   
        b=m; 
    end
       iter = iter+1;

    end
end
root = m;
end
```

Comment: I don't see the problem: if you know the root is between m and b then you make m the new left endpoint, if you know the root is between a and m then you make m the new right endpoint. That's pretty much the whole algorithm other than termination conditions. The only problem I see in your code is that you could find a case where there is actually a root in *both* $[a,m]$ and $[m,b]$, in which case you will make both endpoints be $m$, causing the algorithm to terminate at a point that probably isn't a root. One such situation would be asking your code for a root of $\cos$ on $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: But that case is not a problem if the caller of your code can guarantee that there is exactly one root in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Or one could use `elseif` in the second `if` statement.  What confuses me, on the other hand, is the use of `le` in the condition of the `while` loop.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi le(A,B) is equivalent to A <= B.

Comment: Exactly: `while abs(a-b) <= TOL` is likely to terminate immediately because the condition is false to begin with.

Comment: @Ian According to the pseudocode I read, it said  that it should be 
a_i+1 := a_i
and b=m

but is a_i+1 := a_i really necessery? because I change m for one side each iteration, there should not be any need to alter **a** in that case.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Good catch, I should reverse it! Cheers

Comment: @oxodo Pseudocode typically is written to be easier to follow theoretically; thus for instance you think of bisection as theoretically generating two sequences $a_i,b_i$, and then taking the midpoint of $a_N,b_N$ after some number of iterations $N$. Real numerical code doesn't generally care about these sequences, it just wants the final answer.

Comment: Another observation is that `iter` becomes `i` in the body of the function.

Comment: Thank you @FabioSomenzi , but the code does't want to execute even with all the changes.

Comment: @Ian With all the changes done to my code, it seems that it don't want to execute my function. I will update my code in the original question,

Comment: OK, now what does a call look like?

Comment: @Ian 

f =@(x)x-x^3-1;
a=-2;
b=-1;
TOL = 10^6;

[root, iter] = bisectoin(f,a,b,TOL)

 (I know I've misspelled "bisection":)) I did't relize that the comment would't format. Sorry for the mess

Comment: It looks to me there are too many `end`.  The increment of `iter` is not properly indented.

Comment: Your tolerance is very large.  Did you mean `TOL = 10e-6`?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi woops, yes. You're right. it's typo in the comment. I did use 10^-6 in my call.

Comment: I changed the second if-statment to a elseif. I'm getting a output, but the wrong one. Instead of 0 i'm getting -1.3247. So there must be something wrong with the algorithm

Comment: $-1.3247$ is the value of $x$ for which `f` is approximately $0$.  It is confirmed by `fzero`.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi you're right. Well that saves me some work:) It seems that it worked! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Why am I not able check this question as solved??? :) If somebody would see this..

Comment: I guess because there is no answer to accept.  BTW, your code has one remaining problem.  If you run `bisection(@(x) x-1, 1,2,1e-6)` you'll see that it enters an endless loop because `f(a) == 0`, `f(m)` and `f(b)` are positive, and none of the three `if` statements executes.